# Integrating All Social Feeds In an Android App

Tags: android

Hi guys i am working on an android app where i need to integrate all social feeds namely from Facebook,Twitter,pics From Picasa and Flickr ,Check ins from Four Square etc .I just wanted to know is there any API which works for all the above mentioned social networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to how most APIs work (particularly the fact that you need your own key to use various APIs in most circumstances), I don't believe you will find a single API that accesses all social networking types. However, you can design a library in such a way that it can integrate those feeds for you (effectively giving you what you want, but you'll have to do more of the legwork to get the library you are looking for).

There are [some sites](http://wickedsword.com/combining-social-feeds-with-json-and-jquery) out there that may get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Socialize -- http://www.GetSocialize.com.  We'll soon be launching a realtime activity stream feed which will show all the social actions being taken in the app.  Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but related.

DROdio